# Laravel not displaying data

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display data from the `user` table linked with the `profile` table. I get the data in my vardump but I don't know how to display it one for one.
This is my function :

```
public function show($id)
{
    //Get data from user
    $user = User::find($id);
    //Get the horse count connect to the user
    $horse_count = DB::table('horses')->where('user_id', $id)->count();

    var_dump($user->profile);
    die();
}
```

It returns this :

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#188 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(App\Profile)#189 (24) {
      ["connection":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["table":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["timestamps"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(10) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["country"]=>
        string(11) "Netherlands"
        ["age"]=>
        string(2) "21"
        ["recent_online"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["visitors"]=>
        string(4) "2143"
        ["profile"]=>
        string(17) "Hoi ik ben Martin"
        ["remember_token"]=>
        NULL
        ["created_at"]=>
        NULL
        ["updated_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["original":protected]=>
      array(10) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["country"]=>
        string(11) "Netherlands"
        ["age"]=>
        string(2) "21"
        ["recent_online"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["visitors"]=>
        string(4) "2143"
        ["profile"]=>
        string(17) "Hoi ik ben Martin"
        ["remember_token"]=>
        NULL
        ["created_at"]=>
        NULL
        ["updated_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["relations":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["hidden":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["visible":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["appends":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["guarded":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "*"
      }
      ["dates":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dateFormat":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["casts":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["touches":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["observables":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["morphClass":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      }
  }
}
```

But when I `echo $user->profile->age;` it shows nothing.
For info, I linked the tables `user` and `profile` with eachother with `return $this->belongsTo('App\User');` and `return $this->hasMany('App\Profile');`. I get the data but I just can't display it one for one.

Comment: What is a profile in this context?

Comment: You may want to use eager loading in this case. Look at laravel documentation for more details.

Comment: Profile is a table linked with the id from user table

Comment: @ClearBoth checking it out now!

Comment: @ClearBoth that is exactly what I am doing but it is not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One per one:

```
foreach (User::find($id)->profile as $profile) {
     // Do what you want, e.g.
     echo $profile->age;
}
```

Remember, if a user has many profiles then the relation function name should be plural like `public function profiles()`

Comment: It seems to work, but I don't understand how I get this to blade? Can you help me?

Comment: Of course! You pass your `$user = User::find($id)` -object to the view (e.g. `return view('home.index', compact('user'));`. And in your blade file you use the blade functions: `@foreach ($user->profile as $profile) {{ $profile->age }} @endforeach`